# Extract properties from wp website and view them on new website using js

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress-rest-api

I'm new to js, any assistance would be much appreciated.

I've been assigned with building a website using wordpress and as the title suggests i'm having a hard time with it. I'm being met by an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0", i'm using a cors in order to display the properties.

I've checked through my code and have no spelling error. One suggestion mentioned returning "text.json", but that only returned the html.

```
fetch(corsEnabled)
      .then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
          return response.json();
      })
      .catch(function(error){
          console.log(error);
      })
```

Comment: [Please provide some code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You might have a PHP Error or Warning on Server side. There cannot be any HTML/Text before your JSON Response. Check the URL in your browser if possible to see what's going on.